# Maven resource filtering not working from 'resources' folder

Tags: java, maven

I am having some trouble with Maven's resource filtering. The directory structure is:

```
src
 |-main
    |-filters
    |-java
    |-resources
    |-webapp
```

The POM contains the following:

```xml
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/${environment}/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    ...

</build>
```

I am using NetBeans with '*Copy static resources on save*' but it will only copy the resources if `filtering` is set to `false`. This is forcing me to do a build each time I change a file in the `resources` folder rather than just saving the changed file.

Running `mvn resources:resources` gives the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building core 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-cli) @ core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 77 resources
[INFO] Copying 31 resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.618 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-22T21:24:32+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but when I look in the target folder a modified `struts.xml` file is not updated. I have never used `mvn resources:resources` before so maybe I have the wrong idea about it. Should it not copy the files from `src/main/resources` to `target/[FOLDER]/WEB-INF/classes`?

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Your directory structure is "src/filters", but you refer it as "src/main/filters". Where is a mistake?

Comment: Well spotted. The error was in my description, I have updated the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "`mvn resources:resources` doesn't work"? Does it not copy the resources from `src/main/resources` to the target directory or does the filtering not work?

Comment: I updated question. `mvn resources:resources` didn't seem to do anything. I deleted my `struts.xml` from the `target` folder and re-ran but the `struts.xml` didn't get copied to `target`.

Answer (score 3):

> Should it not copy the files from src/main/resources to target/[FOLDER]/WEB-INF/classes

No, it should copy those files to `target/classes`. The maven-war-plugin is responsible for copying the content of this folder to the `WEB-INF/classes` (during the package phase). So instead run `mvn package`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. Everything works as expected when using the command line. The problem was with NetBeans. I found an [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=214828) (from 2012) stating that the IDE can not use filtered resources in some circumstances and it places a badge over the folder to indicate that.

To workaround this I have:

- Opened the project properties;
- Clicked on `Action`;
- Clicked `Add custom` and named it `mvn:resources`;
- In `execute goals` I entered `resources:resources package`;
- Now I can right click on the project and select `custom` > `mvn:resources` in order to copy the modification to the `package` directory.

JRebel now picks up the changes so I am happy.